# Given a graph G = (V, E) prove e <= n(n-1)/2 for all n

Tags: graph, graph-theory, proof

I'm trying to figure out to solve this problem: Given a graph G = (V, E) prove e <= n(n-1)/2 for all n, where e is the number of edges and n is the number of vertices.

I'm thinking that I should somehow be using math induction to figure out the correct answer and use n = 1 or 0 for my hypothesis, but I'm getting a little stuck on what to do after -- if I assume n = k, then: e <= (k+1)k/2.  and if n = k+1 then e <= k(k-1)/2.

As I understand it, each vertex has n-1 possible edges coming out, and there are n total vertices, which is where n(n-1) comes from and dividing by 2 gets rid of the repeats.  But I am unsure how I am to prove this.

Comment: Try Math Overflow instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: Hint: n(n-1)/2 is a special number: it is the sum of all the natural numbers from 1 through n - 1.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false for multi-graphs. Take the graph:

```
 /---\
O-----O
```

There are two vertices (`O`) and two edges; therefore `n=2,e=2` and substituting into `n(n-1)/2 <= e` gives `1 <= 2` which is false.

However, if you restrict the graph to be simple - disallowing looping edges (where both ends of the edge terminate at the same vertex), multi-edges  (where two edges connect the same pair of vertices) and that the graph is undirected - then the property holds.

Consider a complete graph `K_n` (with `n` vertices): each of the `n` vertices is incident to the other `n-1` vertices via a connecting edge therefore there are `n(n-1)` connections from one vertex to another; given that edges are undirected then this will count each edge twice (i.e counting from vertex `A` to vertex `B` and vice versa) then the total number of edges will be `n(n-1)/2`.

Any graph `G_n` (with `n` vertices) will be a sub-graph of `K_n` (since you cannot add any more edges to `K_n` without creating multi- or looping edges) then there must be equal or fewer edges in `G_n` than in `K_n`.

Thus `e <= n(n-1)/2` for all simple graphs.

If you further restrict the graph to be planar then you can state that `e <= 3n - 6` (when `n > 2`).